# grepping a list of URLS for a keyword in domain portion

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I have a big list(millions) of URLs in a file (one per line), like the following:

```
http://someDomain.com/articlex=123&b=23

http://KEYWORDindomain.net/blahblah 

http://anotherKEYWORDindomain.org/blahblah/blip/q=123 

http://blabkkk.org/KEYWORD/blip/q=123

 (etc)
```

I want to print out all the URLS where a certain keyword appears *in the domain portion* of the URL.

ex.

```
grep <regex>KEYWORD<regex> file

output
======
http://KEYWORDindomain.net/blahblah
http://anotherKEYWORDindomain.org/blahblah/blip/q=123
```

i figure this should be easily grep-able but having trouble figuring out the regex. Maybe i need to  pipe a couple commands to achieve my desired results?

the closest i've gotten is:  grep "http://.*\?/"

Anyone have a good way to do this using shell commands?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
\b(https?|ftp|file)://[^/\s]*KEYWORD[^/\s]*(?:/[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$])?
```

This will match a URL that contains `KEYWORD` in the part before the first slash (if there is any).

Comment: thx for the tip, having trouble getting it to work, here's what i tried and the error i got: 
mike@mike-desktop:~$ grep "\b(https?|ftp|file)://[^/\s]*vacation[^/\s]*(?:/[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$])?" urls.txt
bash: ,: unrecognized history modifier
mike@mike-desktop:~$ egrep \b(https?|ftp|file)://[^/\s]*vacation[^/\s]*(?:/[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$])? urls.txt 
bash: ,: unrecognized history modifier

Comment: Try `grep` with the `--perl-regexp` option. Also, I'm not sure if you need to double the backslashes to escape them.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest expression that qualifies is this (you trust that anything that has http:// in it is the start of a URL, which may not always be true, but...):

```
grep 'http://[^/]*KEYWORD'
```

If you want to get fancy with more URL prefixes, try this:

```
grep '\<[a-z]*://[^/]*KEYWORD'
```

The [^/]* is the key, it means 'any character except a /, zero occurrence or any number of times'.

If you know that the file you need to sort lists one URL per line, and that the URL starts at the beginning of the line, then you can protect yourself form unlikely but potentially spurious http:// in the middle of a line with the following:

```
grep '^http://[^/]*KEYWORD'
```

Just like Tim suggested, you can always keep spaces out of this too, if you have reasons to think that your URL list may contain spaces (I prefer the old method of listing space and tab):

```
grep '^http://[^/ \t]*KEYWORD'
```

Hope this helps.